# How to create a string from a pre-processor macro

Tags: macros, verilog, system-verilog

I have a preprocessor macro that represents a hierarchical path into my design.

Example:

```
`define HPATH top.chip.block
```

I need to construct a string which holds the value of `` `HPATH ``, so in my example the string should equal `top.chip.block`.

Is there a way to construct such a string?

None of the following attempts worked:

```
string hpath;
hpath = "`HPATH";     // Results in hpath = "`HPATH"
hpath = \"``HPATH\";  // Doesn't compile
hpath = `HPATH;       // Doesn't compile
```

I want `hpath` to be equivalent to doing this assignment `hpath = "top.chip.block"`, but by using `` `HPATH `` instead of specifying the path again.

I cannot use `%m` because I need the string within my top-level UVM environment, not within a module.

A little more background: the reason I want to do this is because I am using backdoor register access in the UVM class library. The backdoor API requires setting the hdl_path to the blocks within the design, as a string. I already have `defines for the hierarchical paths and am trying to reuse those when specifying the hdl_paths so I don't have the same path defined twice. My testbench will use both the hierarchical path and the string path.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

It's not possible to use a `define macro within a string literal. According to the SystemVerilog LRM:

> Macro substitution and argument substitution shall not occur within string literals.

However a string literal can be constructed by using a macro that takes an argument and including the quotes in the macro by using ``"`.

Again, from the LRM:

> An `" overrides the usual lexical meaning of " and indicates that the expansion shall include the quotation
>   mark, substitution of actual arguments, and expansions of embedded macros. This allows string literals to be
>   constructed from macro arguments.

So this works:

```
`define STRINGIFY(x) `"x`"
`define HPATH top.chip.block
string hpath = `STRINGIFY(`HPATH);
$display(hpath);                       // Output: "top.chip.block"
```

The example code can be run here: http://www.edaplayground.com/s/4/879

Answer (score 3):

The use of `$sformatf` allows additional information to be added if needed.

```
`define STRINGIFY(DEFINE) $sformatf("%0s", `"DEFINE`")
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you're looking for.

```
`define HPATH `"top.chip.block`"
string hpath = `HPATH;
```

As toolic pointed out, the escape sequence %m will give you the current hierarchy when used in a $display statement so that may be a better option.

Comment: Not exactly - I still need to use `\`HPATH` as a hierarchical reference in some other contexts so simply defining the macros as a string will not work.

Answer (score -1):

`define   HPATH  top.chip.block

string    hpath = `"`HPATH`";

Hope it helps.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).