# How to create a string from a pre-processor macro with arguments

Tags: macros, verilog, system-verilog, stringification

I'm trying to stringify a macro in System Verilog, so I can use it in a string for printing.

I created a STRINGIFY macro:

```
`define STRINGIFY(x) `"x`"
```

as suggested here:
[How to create a string from a pre-processor macro](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15373113/how-to-create-a-string-from-a-pre-processor-macro/15376637#15376637)

However, the macro I'm trying to stringify takes arguments.

Consider the following code:

```
`define STRINGIFY(x) `"x`"
`define HPATH(signal) top.chip.block.signal
string hpath = `STRINGIFY(`HPATH(wire));
$display(hpath);                       // Output: "`HPATH(wire)"
```

I want the output to be
`"top.chip.block.wire"`
instead.

Notice that the `HPATH` macro takes an argument `wire`.

This is the example code run here: http://www.edaplayground.com/x/CKB

EDIT:
The problem is that the `STRINGIFY macro **stops** the expansion of the macro inside when the macro inside has arguments.
For example:

```
`define STRINGIFY(x) `"x`"
`define HPATH top.chip.block
`define HPATH_SIGNAL(signal) top.chip.block.signal

$display(`"`HPATH`"); // correctly outputs "top.chip.block"
$display(`STRINGIFY(`HPATH)); // correctly outputs "top.chip.block"
$display(`"`HPATH_SIGNAL(sig)`"); // correctly outputs "top.chip.block.sig"
$display(`STRINGIFY(`HPATH_SIGNAL(sig))); // incorrectly outputs "`HPATH_SIGNAL(sig)"
```

It seems that the `HPATH_SIGNAL(sig) is not resolved when nested inside the `STRINGIFY macro

The question is why isn't the HPATH_SIGNAL(sig) expanded on the last line?

Here's the example code run:
http://www.edaplayground.com/x/RF2

Answer (score 1):

I don't know when this was introduced to VCS, but you can force VCS to be LRM compliant using the below option.

```
-p1800_macro_expansion

This option is used for LRM compliance to support macro
expansion. This option produces results that are more LRM-
compliant and accurate especially for SystemVerilog macros.
```

Answer (score 0):

An `" overrides the usual lexical meaning of " and indicates that the expansion shall include the quotation mark, substitution of actual arguments, and expansions of embedded macros. This allows string literals to be constructed from macro arguments.

A mixture of `" and " is allowed in the macro text, however the use of " always starts a string literal and must have a terminating ". Any characters embedded inside this string literal, including ",  the " starts a string literal whose last charater is  is terminated by the " of ".

```
`define HPATH(signal) `"top.chip.block.signal`"
`define W wire
module a;
  initial begin
    string hpath = `HPATH(wire);
    //string hpath = `HPATH(`W);
    $display("%s",hpath);
  end
endmodule
```

> output : top.chip.block.wire

Hope you understand the context of `" and " (or just a macro definition)

Comment: Well, I still want to use the HPATH macro as a hierarchical path (without quotes). I will revise my question since I narrowed down the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I don't agree with the output you are getting on EDA playground. I am getting the desired output using ModelSim/Questa. Regardless of where the macro argument text is expanded *before* or *after* being passed through the outer level macro (The LRM says *after*) the `" should have allowed the macro that was passed through to be expanded.

Comment: Yes, the issue appears in EDA playground when running with VCS 2014 and older versions of the Icarus Verilog simulator.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be a VCS issue.

When the same code is run on *Icarus Verilog 0.10.0* and *Riviera-PRO EDU 2015.06* simulators the output is correct.

The issue appears when running with *VCS 2014.12* simulator.